# $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{T_k}$ $ = {1\over 2}{(2n+1)^{3/2}-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

if $$T_n = {4n+\sqrt{4n^2-1}\over \sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}$$
(a).prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{T_k} = {1\over 2}\{{(2n+1)^{3\over2}-1}\}$$
And (b)use telescopic series to prove the result.

Comment: More information would be helpful when making a question.Such that where does this problem come from ,or what have you tried until now.

Comment: I think it's just a application of substituting  alphabet for certain number.In this case you could replace $a$ for $\sqrt{2n+1}$ and $b$ for $\sqrt{2n-1}$.Then the denominator is $a^2+b^2+ab$ and member is $a+b$.Multiply $a-b$ at the same time you will get $\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2-b^2}$ while $a^2-b^2=2$. The rest should be easy for you right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write $$T_{n} = \frac{4n+\sqrt{4n^2-1}}{\left(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}\right)}\times \frac{\left(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}\right)}$$

Now Using $$\bullet \; 4n+\sqrt{4n^2-1} = (\sqrt{2n+1})^2+(\sqrt{2n-1})^2+2\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n-1)} $$

$$\bullet\; 4n+\sqrt{4n^2-1}  = (2n+1)+(2n-1)+2\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$

So we get $$T_{n} = \frac{(2n+1)+(2n-1)+2\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n-1)}}{2}\times \left(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}\right)$$

So $$T_{n} = \frac{(2n+1)\sqrt{2n+1}-(2n-1)\sqrt{2n-1}}{2}$$

Now Calculate $$\sum^{n}_{r=1}T_{r} = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\left[(2n+1)\sqrt{2n+1}-(2n-1)\sqrt{2n-1}\right]$$

Now we Expand above Summation.

Comment: there is a mistake how can u write $4n+\sqrt{4n^2-1}$ as ${\left[\left(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}\right)\right]^2}$

Comment: User I have edited it.

Comment: No you have not

Comment: Sorry  user283172 I have edited it.